# Way to insert value into select list option by use Laravel Collection methods.

Tags: javascript, laravel, drop-down-menu, selectlist

Below code make job_type select box by reading `job_type` field from Job Table in the DB.

Also, it working how if a list selected as **Andre** in the select box then Modal will show.

***Question.***

1. Below list box showing lists that predefined values in the table. 
   How could I pre-define list value **Andre** into the list even if it
   is not included in the DB.

[image]

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
  ---
  $job_types = Job::all()->pluck('job_type', 'job_type')->unique();
  ---
}
```

**View**(select box.)

```
<!-- Job Type Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
    {!! Form::label('job_type', 'Job Type:') !!}    
    {!! Form::select('job_types', $job_types, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'job_type']) !!}
</div>
```

**View**(Modal box to insert new `job_type`)

```
{{--  Modal box define start  --}}
<div class="modal fade" id="jobListModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Sett inn ny jobb emne</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>New Job Type:</p>
              <input type="text" id="textInput">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal -->
{{--  Modal box define end  --}}
```

**Jquery code**(for Modal)

```
$('#job_type').on('mouseleave touchend', function (e) {
    if ('Andre' == this.value) {
        $("#jobStopModal").modal("show");
    }
});
$('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
    var newType = $('input#textInput').val();
    $('select#job_type option:last')
        .after('<option value="' + newType + '" selected="selected" >' + newType + '</option>');
    $('#jobListModal').modal('hide');
});
```

**Test result after hearing advice**

I followed @Nouphal.M's advice, so I revised some code in the Controller as below and it is working good, but I got a below image of list view. It is expressed as being included in the subcategory of option list '0'.

How could I modify to out of option list? and why did this result came out?

Thank you in advenced.

```
$customData = array('**NY**'=>'**NY**');

$job_types = Job::whereNotNull('job_type')
->orderBy('job_type', 'desc')
->pluck('job_type', 'job_type')
->push($customData)
->unique();
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try the below:

```
  $job_types = Job::all()->pluck('job_type', 'job_type')->unique();
  $customData = (object) array('customValue'=>'customLabel');
  $job_types->push($customData);
```

Have a look at [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) . Hope this is of any help

Comment: I revised question, could you give more detailed advice, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need just one item:

You can use 'placeholder' option (it will be visible as a select placeholder but not selectable).

```
{{ Form::select('job_types', $job_types, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'job_type', 'placeholder' => 'Job Type...']) }}
```

or prepend method of collection

```
{{ Form::select('job_types', $job_types->prepend('Job Type...', ''), null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'job_type']) }}
```

But if you need more than one - you can use concat method of collection in your controller:

```
$job_types = Job::all()->pluck('job_type', 'job_type')->concat([1 => 'Job type 1', 2 => 'Job type 2'])->unique();
```

Comment: your advice was good, but in this case did not work. but I got hint to future development, :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the result by replace `push` to `put` as below code.

```
    $job_types = Job::whereNotNull('job_type')
    ->orderBy('job_type', 'desc')
    ->pluck('job_type', 'job_type')
    ->put('**NY**', '**NY**')
    ->unique();
```

Comment: Or ->put(...$customData)